# performSelectorOnMainThread when file is deleted IOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsfilemanager

How can I use the method:

```
[receiver performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(sel) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO]
```

to run another method when the deletion of a file from path is done? This is how it is done:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
                [fileManager removeItemAtPath:myFilePath error:NULL];
```

Comment: Do not repeat your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, removeItemAtPath: has a BOOL return type, meaning that if will return YES or NO depending on whether or not it was successful, therefore implying that it finished writing. That being said, you can wrap the call in an if statement and call performSelectorOnMainThread: from within it.

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ([fileManager removeItemAtPath:myFilePath error:nil]) {
    [receiver performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(sel) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO]
}
```

From [the docs:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/removeItemAtPath%3aerror%3a)

> Return Value YES if the item was removed successfully or if path was
>   nil. Returns NO if an error occurred. If the delegate aborts the
>   operation for a file, this method returns YES. However, if the
>   delegate aborts the operation for a directory, this method returns NO.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Grand Central Dispatch instead:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
BOOL didRemoveFile = [fileManager removeItemAtPath:myFilePath error:NULL];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if (didRemoveFile) {
       // do something like inform everything went ok
    } else {
        // you could inform something bad happened here
    }

    // or perhaps you want a method to get called, every time
});
```

Comment: This works at times. sometimes the method is not called. I want it to be always called when the deletion is over

Comment: Check my latest edit. Just call something outside of the if statement.